# PIVPN RPI4 doesn't create OVPN file only creates .conf file, doesn't work with tunnelblick

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I just finished setting up the PIVPN with my RPI 4. Went through the setup, and everything seems peachy yet it gives me a .conf file and not an OVPN file when I add a new profile. Does PIVPN not work anymore?

When I try to start the .conf file with tunnelblick it tells me "Tunnelblick could not find a 'tun' or 'tap' option in the OpenVPN configuration file".

Any help, tips, or tricks would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

lol.....the spacebar....selects the settings.....durrrrrrr. I hit space on OpenVPN and blammo we're golden